# Optimized (armv7) versus Standard (armv6 armv7)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I got the error message below, and I found a solution to it was to set the Architectures field in Xcode to Optimizied(amrv7) gets me past it. But at what cost? What do I lose of gain in doing this and why does this fix it. I like fixes, but dont like fixing things so blind to the consequences.

ld: ldr 12-bit displacement out of range (4312 max +/-4096) in _AudioFileGetProperty$stub in _AudioFileGetProperty$stub from /Users/jake/Documents/Ir/build/Ir.build/Release-iphoneos/Ir.build/Objects-normal/armv6/Ir
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Optimizied(amrv7) will make your app run only on the iPhone 3GS and higher.
You will lose any user with an iPhone, iPhone 3G and iPod touch.

Comment: Well most users have switch to the iPhone 3GS and newer versions of the iPod Touch. The iPad has always had an ARMv7 processor.